# Javascript calculator equal function failing

Tags: javascript

I have created a calculator using JavaScript. When I chain together multiple math problems I get the answer I desire until I try and get the end result with the = button. When I do only two numbers the = button works perfectly fine.  I have my code set up to set the a mathHoldOne and mathHoldTwo. Both contain a number and a boolean if its set or not. I have checked dev tools to see what the difference is between a problem with two numbers and a problem with 2+ numbers and I can't seem to find the issue. [codepen](https://codepen.io/tchbell/full/WdjxdG/)

```
const view = {
    //Updates view when buttons are clicked
    updateView: function () {
        let viewScreen = document.getElementsByClassName('js-view')[0];
        let miniView = document.getElementsByClassName('mini-view')[0];
        viewScreen.innerHTML = '';
        miniView.innerHTML = '';
        const jsContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('js-container')[0];
        jsContainer.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            let show = e.target.innerHTML;
            viewScreen.innerHTML += show;
        });
    },
    //have a handler that sets what each button does with event delegation
    btnHandle: function () {
        let mathType = {"type": undefined};
        let mathHoldOne = {"num": 0, "set": false};
        let mathHoldTwo = {"num": 0, "set": false};
        let btnHandler = document.querySelector('.js-container');

        btnHandler.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
            let btn = event.target;
            let screenValue = document.querySelector('.js-view');
            let miniView = document.querySelector('.mini-view');
            switch (btn.className) {
                //clears whats in the view window
                case('cell clear'):
                    screenValue.innerHTML = '';
                    miniView.innerHTML = '';
                    mathHoldOne.num = 0;
                    mathHoldOne.set = false;
                    mathHoldTwo.num = 0;
                    mathHoldTwo.set = false;
                    mathType.type = undefined;
                    break;
                case('cell math multiply'):
                    //assigns mathHoldTwo.num if mathHoldOne.set is true and blanks the screenValue
                    if (mathHoldOne.set) {
                        mathHoldTwo.num = parseInt(screenValue.innerHTML);
                        mathHoldTwo.set = true;
                        screenValue.innerHTML = '';
                        //if mathHoldOne.set is false it assigns mathHoldOne.num and sets the set property to true
                        //also sets mathType.type to multiply
                    } else {
                        mathHoldOne.num = parseInt(screenValue.innerHTML);
                        mathHoldOne.set = true;
                        screenValue.innerHTML = '';
                        mathType.type = "mulitply";
                    }
                    if (mathHoldOne.set && mathHoldTwo.set) {
                        //if both numbers are set cycle through calcFunc to find which mathType.type matches
                        //and execute that function with the two values
                        for (let name in calcFunc) {
                            if (mathType.type === name) {
                                miniView.innerHTML = calcFunc[name](mathHoldOne.num, mathHoldTwo.num);
                                mathHoldOne.num = calcFunc[name](mathHoldOne.num, mathHoldTwo.num);
                            }
                        }
                        mathHoldTwo.num = 0;
                        mathHoldTwo.set = false;
                        mathType.type = 'multiply';
                    }
                    break;
                case('cell math divide'):
                    if (mathHoldOne.set) {
                        mathHoldTwo.num = parseInt(screenValue.innerHTML);
                        mathHoldTwo.set = true;
                        screenValue.innerHTML = '';
                    } else {
                        mathHoldOne.num = parseInt(screenValue.innerHTML);
                        mathHoldOne.set = true;
                        screenValue.innerHTML = '';
                        mathType.type = "divide";
                    }
                    if (mathHoldOne.set && mathHoldTwo.set) {
                        for (let name in calcFunc) {
                            if (mathType.type === name) {
                                miniView.innerHTML = calcFunc[name](mathHoldOne.num, mathHoldTwo.num);
                                mathHoldOne.num = calcFunc[name](mathHoldOne.num, mathHoldTwo.num);
                            }
                        }
                        mathHoldTwo.num = 0;
                        mathHoldTwo.set = false;
                        mathType.type = 'divide';
                    }
                    break;
                case('cell math add'):
                    if (mathHoldOne.set) {
                        mathHoldTwo.num = parseInt(screenValue.innerHTML);
                        mathHoldTwo.set = true;
                        screenValue.innerHTML = '';
                    } else {
                        mathHoldOne.num = parseInt(screenValue.innerHTML);
                        mathHoldOne.set = true;
                        screenValue.innerHTML = '';
                        mathType.type = "add";
                    }
                    if (mathHoldOne.set && mathHoldTwo.set) {
                        for (let name in calcFunc) {
                            if (mathType.type === name) {
                                miniView.innerHTML = calcFunc[name](mathHoldOne.num, mathHoldTwo.num);
                                mathHoldOne.num = calcFunc[name](mathHoldOne.num, mathHoldTwo.num);
                            }
                        }
                        ;
                        mathHoldTwo.num = 0;
                        mathHoldTwo.set = false;
                        mathType.type = 'add';
                    }
                    break;
                case('cell math subtract'):
                    if (mathHoldOne.set) {
                        mathHoldTwo.num = parseInt(screenValue.innerHTML);
                        mathHoldTwo.set = true;
                        screenValue.innerHTML = '';
                    } else {
                        mathHoldOne.num = parseInt(screenValue.innerHTML);
                        mathHoldOne.set = true;
                        screenValue.innerHTML = '';
                        mathType.type = "subract";
                    }
                    if (mathHoldOne.set && mathHoldTwo.set) {
                        for (let name in calcFunc) {
                            if (mathType.type === name) {
                                miniView.innerHTML = calcFunc[name](mathHoldOne.num, mathHoldTwo.num);
                                mathHoldOne.num = calcFunc[name](mathHoldOne.num, mathHoldTwo.num);
                            }
                        }
                        ;
                        mathHoldTwo.num = 0;
                        mathHoldTwo.set = false;
                        mathType.type = 'subtract';
                    }
                    break;
                case('cell equal'):
                    mathHoldTwo.num = parseInt(screenValue.innerHTML);
                    if (mathType.type === "add") {
                        screenValue.innerHTML = calcFunc.add(mathHoldOne.num, mathHoldTwo.num);
                        miniView.innerHTML = calcFunc.add(mathHoldOne.num, mathHoldTwo.num);
                        mathHoldTwo.num = 0;
                        mathHoldOne.num = 0;
                        mathHoldOne.set = false;
                    } else if (mathType.type === "subract") {
                        screenValue.innerHTML = calcFunc.subtract(mathHoldOne.num, mathHoldTwo.num);
                        miniView.innerHTML = calcFunc.subtract(mathHoldOne.num, mathHoldTwo.num);
                        mathHoldOne.num = (mathHoldOne.num - mathHoldTwo.num);
                        mathHoldTwo.num = 0;
                        mathHoldOne.num = 0;
                        mathHoldOne.set = false;
                    }
                    else if (mathType.type === "mulitply") {
                        screenValue.innerHTML = calcFunc.multiply(mathHoldOne.num, mathHoldTwo.num);
                        miniView.innerHTML = calcFunc.multiply(mathHoldOne.num, mathHoldTwo.num);
                        mathHoldOne.num = (mathHoldOne.num * mathHoldTwo.num);
                        mathHoldTwo.num = 0;
                        mathHoldOne.num = 0;
                        mathHoldOne.set = false;
                    } else if (mathType.type === "divide") {
                        screenValue.innerHTML = calcFunc.divide(mathHoldOne.num, mathHoldTwo.num);
                        miniView.innerHTML = calcFunc.divide(mathHoldOne.num, mathHoldTwo.num);
                        mathHoldOne.num = (mathHoldOne.num / mathHoldTwo.num);
                        mathHoldTwo.num = 0;
                        mathHoldOne.num = 0;
                        mathHoldOne.set = false;
                    }
                    break;
            }
            console.log(mathHoldOne, mathHoldTwo, mathType.type);
        })
    }

};

view.updateView();
view.btnHandle();
const calcFunc = {
    add: function (x, y) {
        return x + y;
    },
    subtract: function (x, y) {
        return x - y;
    },
    multiply: function (x, y) {
        return x * y;
    },
    divide: function (x, y) {
        return x / y;
    },
    clear: function () {
        let view = document.querySelector('js-view');
        view.innerHTML = '';
    }
}
```

Comment: ever think of using `eval` or `new Function` for basic calculation problems? I think you have a problem with the multiply function as well (seems to be miss written in the `case ('cell equal')` statement ifs block). I also believe your code is overly complex (for example, on every case block you are calling this `if(mathHoldOne.set && mathHoldTwo.set)`, but you evaluate it somewhat dynamically. For the rest, you seem to forget that `5 + 3 * 5` is `20` while I think your code would evaluate it as `40` as you execute the statements at once

Answer (score 0):

Though it might not provide a single answer to your question, I thought I could offer a different version of your calculator.

The main thing here is that the calculation is lifted through the [`new Function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) statement, which allows you to execute a string as (an isolated piece of) JavaScript code.

The calculation gets built up as you click the buttons. As it doesn't exclude giving in false statements, the code is put in a try/catch block. In the catch block you could indicate to the user that the calculation he entered was invalid, in the current version it just logs the error and returns 0.

```
function executeCalculation( calculation ) {
  var fn = new Function( `return (${calculation});` );
  try {
    return fn();
  } catch (ex) {
    console.log( ex );
    return 0;
  }
}
```

The fact that the full calculation gets evaluated at once is an advantage as then the [order of operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) is preserved as expected. An example of this order would be the one I left in the comments, trying to calculating `5 + 3 * 5` should result in `20`, but in your current calculation it will evaluate to `5 + 3 = 8 * 5 = 40`.

```js
// attach basic event handlers
document
  .querySelectorAll('button')
  .forEach( 
    button => button.addEventListener('click', updateCalculation ) 
  );
  
// some global variables
let currentCalculation = '';
let currentValue = 0;
let memory = 0;
  
// event handler for clicking on the buttons
function updateCalculation( e ) {
  let source = e.target;
  if  (!source) {
    return;
  }
  // use the data-type attribute to check what action needs to be performed
  let type = source.getAttribute('data-type');
  if (!type) {
    return;
  }
  switch (type) {
    case '=':
      currentValue = executeCalculation( currentCalculation );
      currentCalculation = '';
      break;
    case 'clear-view':
      currentCalculation = '';
      break;
    case 'clear-all':
      currentValue = 0;
      currentCalculation = '';
      break;
    case 'store':
      memory = currentValue;
      break;
    case 'retrieve':
      currentCalculation += memory;
      break;
    case 'clear':
      memory = 0;
      break;
    case '*':
    case '+':
    case '-':
    case '/':
      // in case the currentCalculation is empty, it should start with the current value instead
      if (currentCalculation === '') {
        currentCalculation = currentValue;
      }
      currentCalculation += type;
      break;
    default:
      currentCalculation += type;
  }
  // update the screen with the changes
  updateView( currentValue, currentCalculation );
}

function updateView( value, calculation ) {
  document.querySelector('.entry').innerHTML = value;
  document.querySelector('.current-query').innerHTML = calculation;
}

// executes and returns the result of the calculation
function executeCalculation( calculation ) {
  var fn = new Function( `return (${calculation});` );
  try {
    return fn();
  } catch (ex) {
    console.log( ex );
    return 0;
  }
}
```

```css
.calculator {
  background-color: #000;
  display: inline-block;
}
button {
  margin: 3px;
}
.entry {
  display: block;
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: right;
  border: inset #fff 1px;
}
.current-query {
  font-size: 0.7em;
  text-align: right;
  color: #fff;
  height: 20px;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}
.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="calculator">
<div class="header">
  <div class="view">
    <div class="entry">0</div>
    <div class="current-query"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="quick-buttons">
  <button type="button" data-type="clear-view">CE</button>
  <button type="button" data-type="clear-all">C</button>
  <button type="button" data-type="store">M</button>
  <button type="button" data-type="retrieve">MR</button>
  <button type="button" data-type="clear">MC</button>
</div>
<div class="main-buttons row">
  <div class="numbers column">
    <div class="row">
      <button type="button" data-type="7">7</button>
      <button type="button" data-type="8">8</button>
      <button type="button" data-type="9">9</button>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <button type="button" data-type="4">4</button>
      <button type="button" data-type="5">5</button>
      <button type="button" data-type="6">6</button>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <button type="button" data-type="1">1</button>
      <button type="button" data-type="2">2</button>
      <button type="button" data-type="3">3</button>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <button type="button" data-type="0">0</button>
      <button type="button" data-type=".">.</button>
      <button type="button" data-type="=">=</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="operations row">
    <div class="column">
      <button type="button" data-type="+">+</button>
      <button type="button" data-type="-">-</button>
      <button type="button" data-type="*">*</button>
      <button type="button" data-type="/">/</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```